# How to remove unwanted path in cmd

Tags: python, windows, powershell, path

When I try to use pip command I get error internal or external command, it occurs because I install new version of python 3.9 then remove it but I think command prompt is still using pip from 3.9 directory.  How do I remove unwanted entries from my `PATH`? When I use the echo command I see python 3.9 and I need to remove it.

```
C:\Users\Rio>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Rio\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin;"C:\Program Files\Python38;C:\Program Files\Python38";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your PATH by following instructions here: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

You may also want to consider using a virtual environment

```sh
python3.8 -m venv venv
.\venv\bin\activate.bat
```

Then your computer will use the corresponding pip. I'd also bet that you have a pip installed that's called `pip3.8`. Try running that explicitly.

Comment: yeah I'm using vitrual method but how do I change version of my python currently it automatically take 3.8.8 64 bit and I need to use 3.8.5 32 bit

Comment: a 64-bit python can do everything 32-bit can. I'm not sure what your use-case is. You should look up how to run multiple versions of python on windows or uninstall python completely from your machine, update the path to remove any entry with python and then install the version you want.